# Android List View duplicates Edit Text values on scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I have a `listview` with one `textview` and a `edit text` in each row. If i am setting a value in one edit text field and then on scrolling down, i am getting a duplicate value of that entered field  value in some other edit text field. How can i resolve this issue?

My adapter class is as shown below:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private Context       context;
  private String[]  names;
  ViewHolder holder;

  static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView text;
    public EditText editText;
  }

  public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] names) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, names);
    this.context = context;
    this.names = names;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_design, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);         
    } else {            
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    String s = names[position];
    holder.text.setText(s);
    return convertView;
  }
}
```

I have referred this links:
[Listview duplicate action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243888/listview-duplicate-action?rq=1), [Android listview duplicates the item on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398529/android-listview-duplicates-the-item-on-scroll?rq=1)

Answer (score 5):

Firstly Reason of this issue is Listview Reuses its view when scrolls ,
So we should have a logic in our get view to manage that

```
if(convertview == null)
{
 //code here 
}else {
 //code here 
}
```

, 
but if you dont want to reuse then you can use following :

```
 @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 500;
}
```

Comment: what is 500 here, can we change it. plz explain

Comment: If we need to show different type of view in list-view then its good to use  getViewTypeCount()
You can use 0 here as you only want to show one type of view in listview

Comment: If you really want to use this **getViewTypeCount** hack (which is *very VERY* bad - because no recylcing happens), you should set **getViewTypeCount** to return the size of items...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below :

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private Context       context;
  private String[]  names;

  static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView text;
    public EditText editText;
  }

  public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] names) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, names);
   this.context = context;
    this.names = names;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_design, parent, null);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        viewHolder.editText = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);         
    }          
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)rowView.getTag();


    String s = names[position];
    holder.text.setText(s);
    return rowView;
  }
}
```

For more information see [This link.](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best that I've been able to think of yet. But try this as a workaround. I agree that there could be a better / cleaner solution to this problem.

The problem you are facing is because of `ListView` recycling the views for better performance.

First of all, can you change the data to `List` instead of an array and make changes as below.

```
List<String> names;
List<String> edit;

// In Constructor()
this.names = names;
// Create a list with empty data for the editTexts
int listSize = names.size();
String emptyString = new String("");
List<String> emptyList = new ArrayList<String>(listSize);
for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i ++){
    emptyList.add(emptyString);
}
this.edit = emptyList;

// In getView()
// add watcher to editText and when it is changed, update the value in 'edit'
// Simply set the corresponding values to this row to the editText
holder.text.setText(names.get(position));
holder.editText.setText(edit.get(position));
```

Can you see if this solves your problem in the short run.

You can see how to use the watched from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11181721/592025

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

My original solution below will work for this use case, but a much better solution is that of the `ViewHolder` pattern, as touched on by HailNaRoz. Although it isn't explained by HailNaRoz why his solution works, that solution uses a `ViewHolder` to aid `View` reuse and is the preferred method adopted by Google and the Android Dev community. The `ViewHolder` keeps a reference to the `Views` (`EditText`, `TextView`, `ImageView` etc), and allows you to add them back into the correct list row when it becomes visible.

Its also worth looking at `RecyclerView`, which has since been introduced to aleviate some of these issues, which forces this methodology. `RecyclerView` is available as a support library that can be added in gradle

See [View Holder in List View](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) and [Creating Lists and Cards (Recycler View)](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

**Original:**

Your problem is that your `EditText` is being recycled. You are keeping hold of a copy of your `TextView` text and resetting it every time it is loaded, but not for your `EditText`.

So you need a way to store the text in the `EditText` field and reset it in your `getView()` method.

To do this you want to set up a `TextWatcher` after your if/else statement in `getView()`:

```
holder.editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                  editTextList.put(position,s.toString());
            }
        });
```

This stores the value in a `HashMap` maintained separately. `position` is taken from the int parameter in your `getView()` method. You will need to make it final.

The `HashMap`:

```
private HashMap<Integer,String> editTextList =new HashMap<Integer,String>();
```

Then when you set your `TextView` text you also want to set the `EditText` value:

```
holder.text.setText(s);
holder.editText.setText(editTextList.get(position));
```

This should keep the current positions `editText` value in the correct `EditText` box.

Comment: Thanks Biddulph for the reply. But its not working for me. Is it working for you ?

Comment: This setup is working for me. Have you tried debugging and making sure that values going in/out of the editTextList are present, and that the TextWatcher listener is being hit properly?